How to tally a list of lists only by considering the first element of the sub list
We need to Tally a list of lists only by considering the first element of the sub lists and then sort the resulting list.
As a simple example consider
list={{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {1, d}, {1, b}, {3, g}, {4, a}, {3, f}, {3, c}}

We need the output as follows:
(* {{4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}},
    {3, {{1, a}, {1, d},{1,b}}},
    {1, {{2, b}}},
    {1, {{4, a}}}} *)

Here the first element in the output {4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}} shows that 4 sub lists contains 3 as first element and so on.
Kindly help us in solving this problem.

Use GroupBy:
Values@GroupBy[list,#[[1]]&,{Length@#,#}&]



It works, but we need to sort the result obtained to get the desired result

@SPJ Reverse@Sort@Values@GroupBy[list, First, {Length@#, #} &]

@SPJ or SortBy[Values@GroupBy[list,#[[1]]&,{Length@#,#}&],-#[[1]]&]

Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {1, d}, {1, b}, {3, g}, {4, a}, {3, 
    f}, {3, c}};
ord = SortBy[list, First] // GroupBy[#, First, Length] & // 
   ReverseSortBy[#, {Values}] & // Keys;
GatherBy[list, First] // 
  Replace[#, k_List :> {Length@k, k}, 1] & // #[[ord]] &



{{4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}}, {3, {{1, a}, {1, d}, {1,
b}}}, {1, {{2, b}}}, {1, {{4, a}}}}


list = 
  {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {1, d}, {1, b}, {3, g}, {4, a}, {3, f}, {3, c}}


la = Transpose[{Length /@ #, #}] & @ GatherBy[list, First]


{{3, {{1, a}, {1, d}, {1, b}}},
{1, {{2, b}}},
{4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}},
{1, {{4, a}}}}

lb = ReverseSortBy[First] @ la


{{4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}},
{3, {{1, a}, {1, d}, {1, b}}},
{1, {{4, a}}},
{1, {{2, b}}}}

To get the wanted result we swap the  last two lists
SubsetMap[Reverse, lb, {-2, -1}]


{{4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}},
{3, {{1, a}, {1, d}, {1, b}}},
{1, {{2, b}}},
{1, {{4, a}}}}


There's a slight bit of ambiguity in your sorting. Here are a few ways...
ReverseSortBy[GroupBy[list, First, {Length@#, #} &], First] // Values

and...
ReverseSortBy[GroupBy[list, First, Comap[{Length, Identity}]], First] // Values

both give
{{4, {{3, c}, {3, g}, {3, f}, {3, c}}}, 
 {3, {{1, a}, {1, d}, {1, b}}}, 
 {1, {{4, a}}}, 
 {1, {{2, b}}}}

In your expected output, however, the last two were switched. So maybe you want an additional layer of sorting based on the first element of the sublists, which could look like...
Sort[
  GroupBy[list, First, Comap[{Length, Identity}]], 
  #1[[1]] >= #2[[1]] && #1[[2, 1, 1]] <= #2[[2, 1, 1]] &] // Values

